# These gifts are for those who don't have enough amount to buy it. These gifts are for whom who don't have enough amount to buy it

Tags: sentence-construction

These gifts are for those who don't have enough amount to buy it. 
These gifts are for whom who don't have enough amount to buy it. 
Which one is correct ? And why

Comment: Sir clarify the difference please

Comment: I suggest reading the question linked by @DJMcMayhem to understand when to use *who* and when to use *whom*.

Comment: who/whom isn't the main issue with either of those sentences.

Comment: Being curious, I searched for the string `"whom who"`. After removing all unrelated strings (such as those in grammar books explaining the usage of *who* and *whom*), one interesting pattern emerged: it appears to be common in dated genealogical writing; the pattern is "***..., by whom, who ...***". For example, *Spencer, his brother, late earl, born August 5, 1738; married, first, in 1757, Jane, daughter of Henry Lawton, esq. of Northampionshire, by **whom**, **who** died Nov. 26, 1767, he had issue: Charles, the present earl.–Frances, born Sept. 10, 1758.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for "who" vs. "whom" :  this is treated elsewhere; subjective is always "who" (as in "who don't have..."), whereas objective is "whom" (in writing, but often "who" in speech!)

However, your examples have other problems:

1) We never write "whom who". Putting the  objective "whom" together with subjective "who" makes no sense in English.  If you had said "them who", it would be closer to understandable, but still wrong.

2) We don't say  "enough amount" . We specify WHAT there is not enough of.  In your examples that would be "don't have enough money".  If you wanted to use "amount" it requires a longer construction "..don't have a sufficient amount [of money]..."

3) "these gifts" are plural, so at the end it should say "to buy them".  If you mean that each person who cannot buy one gift gets one gift, end with "to buy "*one of them*".

4) even then, the idea of buying a "gift" for oneself (if one had enough money) is odd. Not unheard of, but odd.  Perhaps you meant that if the person cannot afford to buy a particular item, then that item would be provided as a gift.

Having said all that, your first example is the closest to correct. Fully corrected, It would read like this:

- These items are [set aside as / to be used as] gifts for those who do not have enough money to buy that item.

But that's a bit long. Perhaps, if the gifts are meant for people who could not afford to buy *any* such gift:

- These items are {to be used as gifts for  / to be given to} those who cannot afford to buy a gift.

(By the way, that is an admirable, charitable practice, to provide gifts for needy people!)